# What is the proper way to Reference a React App From MVC 5 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, redux, axios, create-react-app

React and MVC : i have a react app that i need to be referencing from inside a view , tried all the popular methodologies i could find like react.asp , referencing the build ..etc and i have the following issues:

1-When Referencing the build my server name is dynamic i had to hardcore it in create-react-app , this methodology will not work on my customers machine.

**Package.json**

```
"homepage": "./../../../ServerName/scripts/DashBoard/build/",
```

2-after each code change i have to run the build process since i am referencing the build version, is there any alternative?

3-duo to my usage of authentication inside my mvc project when trying to use a sync calls i will be redirected to the login page with every call unless i reference the app from the context of my mvc project?

4-is there a way to initiate the initial state of my app with the data response from the App load without using any components life cycle methods to make a call to fill in the initial store state?

5- is there any other -more proper- way to reference my react app?

BTW:React Beginner